# Error in my Latex project

Tags: beamer

can someone help me with this error in my latex project? I tried different things different times and I cant figure it out

:/[image]

Comment: Please **never** post code as image, we can not copy it and test it on our computer. So please show us a short compilable tex code in your question we can copy and test.

Answer (score 3):

You have an excess `\end{scope}` in line 33 of your code. Your editor marks this clearly. If you remove this `\end{scope}` this error will be gone. Whether or not the code will run through after you fixed this I can't tell because you only posted a screen shot.

Comment: I fixed it <3 ty again marmot <3

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nk6288